# Can I return values to PHP from an anonymous PL/SQL block?

Tags: php, oracle, plsql, oci8

I'm using PHP and OCI8 to execute anonymous Oracle PL/SQL blocks of code.  Is there any way for me to bind a variable and get its output upon completion of the block, just as I can when I call stored procedures in a similar way?

```
$SQL = "declare
something varchar2 := 'I want this returned';
begin
  --How can I return the value of 'something' into a bound PHP variable?
end;";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define an out parameter by using the keyword `OUT` between the name and data type declaration.  IE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE blah (OUT_PARAM_EXAMPLE OUT VARCHAR2) IS ...
```

If not specified, `IN` is the default.  If you want to use a parameter as both in and out, use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE blah (INOUT_PARAM_EXAMPLE IN OUT VARCHAR2) IS ...
```

The following example creates a procedure with IN and OUT parameters. The procedure is then executed and the results printed out.

```
<?php
   // Connect to database...
   $c = oci_connect("hr", "hr_password", "localhost/XE");
   if (!$c) {
      echo "Unable to connect: " . var_dump( oci_error() );
      die();
   }

   // Create database procedure...
   $s = oci_parse($c, "create procedure proc1(p1 IN number, p2 OUT number) as " .
                     "begin" .
                     "  p2 := p1 + 10;" .
                     "end;");
   oci_execute($s, OCI_DEFAULT);

   // Call database procedure...
   $in_var = 10;
   $s = oci_parse($c, "begin proc1(:bind1, :bind2); end;");
   oci_bind_by_name($s, ":bind1", $in_var);
   oci_bind_by_name($s, ":bind2", $out_var, 32); // 32 is the return length
   oci_execute($s, OCI_DEFAULT);
   echo "Procedure returned value: " . $out_var;

   // Logoff from Oracle...
   oci_free_statement($s);
   oci_close($c);
 ?>
```

Reference:

- [How does one call stored procedures from PHP?](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/PHP_FAQ#How_does_one_call_stored_procedures_from_PHP.3F)

Comment: Does the stored procedure get created permanently or just for this session?  I've used this method to receive OUT parameters from procedures I compiled in the database (it looks like this is doing the same thing, except creating the procedure first).  I'd like to avoid creating any permanent objects in the database when I execute this code.

Comment: @Renderlin: Yes, the example from orafaq.com would create the stored procedure.  You'd need to put the stored procedure in the DECLARE block of an anonymous PLSQL block, and make the `proc1(...` within the BEGIN/END portion in order to not create the procedure.

Comment: @OMGPonies Is out parameters supported in 10g, I was reading that they took out support!

Answer (score -1):

Here my decision:

```
function execute_procedure($procedure_name, array $params = array(), &$return_value = ''){
    $sql = "
    DECLARE
        ERROR_CODE      VARCHAR2(2000);
        ERROR_MSG       VARCHAR2(2000);
        RETURN_VALUE    VARCHAR2(2000);
    BEGIN ";

    $c = $this->get_connection();

    $prms = array();
    foreach($params AS $key => $value) $prms[] = ":$key";
    $prms = implode(", ", $prms);

    $sql .= ":RETURN_VALUE := ".$procedure_name."($prms);";
    $sql .= " END;";


    $s = oci_parse($c, $sql);

    foreach($params AS $key => $value)
    {
        $type = SQLT_CHR;
        if(is_array($value))
        {
            if(!isset($value['value'])) continue;
            if(!empty($value['type'])) $type = $value['type'];
            $value = $value['value'];
        }
        oci_bind_by_name($s, ":$key", $value, -1, $type);
    }

    oci_bind_by_name($s, ":RETURN_VALUE", $return_value, 2000);

    try{
        oci_execute($s);
        if(!empty($ERROR_MSG))
        {
            $data['success'] = FALSE;
            $this->errors = "Ошибка: $ERROR_CODE $ERROR_MSG";
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
    catch(ErrorException $e)
    {
        $this->errors = $e->getMessage();
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

example:

```
    execute_procedure('My_procedure', array('code' => 5454215), $return_value);
    echo $return_value;
```

Comment: Dumping a block of code I hardly consider a valuable answer. Please explain why your code solves the problem of the OP.