# How to read variable from procedure call

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

i'm new to oracle and i've got a problem with reading an output parameter from sql block of code. I've searched many manuals and tutorials but i still can't help myself.

```
$sql = "declare
        A varchar2(16);
        docs.InsT(...);
        end;";
$stid = oci_parse($conn, trim($sql));
oci_execute($stid);
oci_commit($conn);
```

I need the value of A, but i cant rename it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Can I return values to PHP from an anonymous PL/SQL block?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953566/can-i-return-values-to-php-from-an-anonymous-pl-sql-block)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to read the value of 'A' within PHP, you have to use bind variables.  You also need to pass the bind variable in as a reference.  And since you cannot rename your A variable you can do something like this ...

```
$rVal = '';
$sql = "declare
        A varchar2(16);
        docs.InsT(...);
        :rVal := A;
        end;";
$stid = oci_parse($conn, trim($sql));
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':rVal', &$rVal, 16);
oci_execute($stid);
oci_commit($conn);
var_dump($rVal);
```

**$rVal** now contains the value of **A** from oracle.